# Go timeout for Read

Tags: go, concurrency, io

I'd like to do something like unix's `tail -f`, but on the output produced by a process run through Go's `Cmd` facility.

My google-fu is not up to par, evidently, but I did find [this article](https://medium.com/swlh/the-simplest-way-to-handle-timeouts-in-golang-11e371dc6188) which lead me to write the following code, which *almost* works, with a bizarre twist I'm hoping I can get help with.

If it matters, I'm running this on a Mac.

First, here's the minimal program that's compiled to be the `slowroll` executable:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    line := 1
    for {
        fmt.Println("This is line", line)
        line += 1
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    }
}
```

When run, it produces the following output, one line every 2 seconds:

```
    > ./slowroll
    This is line 1
    This is line 2
    This is line 3
    This is line 4
```

And so on.

Here's the package code that attempts to read this, but allowing timeouts so other things can be done:

```golang
package timeout_io

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "errors"
    "time"
)

const BufferSize = 4096

var ErrTimeout = errors.New("timeout")

type TimeoutReader struct {
    b *bufio.Reader
    t time.Duration
}

func NewTimeoutReader(stdOut *bytes.Buffer) *TimeoutReader {
    return &TimeoutReader{b: bufio.NewReaderSize(stdOut, BufferSize), t: 0}
}

func (r *TimeoutReader) SetTimeout(t time.Duration) time.Duration {
    prev := r.t
    r.t = t
    return prev
}

type CallResponse struct {
    Resp string
    Err  error
}

func helper(r *bufio.Reader) <-chan *CallResponse {
    respChan := make(chan *CallResponse, 1)

    go func() {
        resp, err := r.ReadString('\n')

        if err != nil {
            respChan <- &CallResponse{resp, err}
        } else {
            respChan <- &CallResponse{resp, nil}
        }

        return
    }()

    return respChan
}

func (r *TimeoutReader) ReadLineCtx(ctx context.Context) (string, error) {
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        return "", ErrTimeout
    case respChan := <-helper(r.b):
        return respChan.Resp, respChan.Err
    }
}

func (r *TimeoutReader) ReadLine() (string, error) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), r.t)
    defer cancel()

    s, err := r.ReadLineCtx(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    return s, nil
}
```

Finally, here's the `main` code that calls `ReadLine` with timeout:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "sync"
    "time"

    "watcher/timeout_io"
)

func main() {
    var stdOut bytes.Buffer
    var stdErr bytes.Buffer
    runCommand := &exec.Cmd{
        Path:   "./slowroll",
        Stdout: &stdOut,
        Stderr: &stdErr,
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        defer wg.Done()

        err := runCommand.Run()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("failed due to error:", err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
    }(&wg)

    wg.Add(1)

    stdOutReader := timeout_io.NewTimeoutReader(&stdOut)
    stdOutReader.SetTimeout(10 * time.Millisecond)
    index := 1
    for {
        s, err := stdOutReader.ReadLine()
        if err != nil {
            if err != timeout_io.ErrTimeout && err != io.EOF {
                fmt.Println("ReadLine got error", err)
                break
            }
        } else if len(s) > 0 {
            fmt.Println("index: ", index, " s: ", s)
            index += 1
            s = ""
        }
    }

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Done!")
}
```

When run, it produces the following output:

```
    > go run watcher.go
    index:  1  s:  This is line 1
    
    index:  2  s:  This is line 2
    
    index:  3  s:  This is line 2
    
    index:  4  s:  This is line 3
    
    index:  5  s:  This is line 2
    
    index:  6  s:  This is line 3
    
    index:  7  s:  This is line 4
    
    index:  8  s:  This is line 2
    
    index:  9  s:  This is line 3
    
    index:  10  s:  This is line 4
    
    index:  11  s:  This is line 5
```

And so on.

Occasionally, some `slowroll` output lines don't show up at all; which lines get repeated is random.

So that's my mystery... I don't see where the (apparent) loop is happening that causes the lines to be produced multiple times.

Thanks very much in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Simplify the code by creating a pipe and reading from that pipe:

```
cmd := exec.Command("./slowroll")
stdout, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

s := bufio.NewScanner(stdout)
for s.Scan() {
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", s.Bytes())
}
```

If your goal is to monitor the combined output of stderr and stdin, then use the same pipe for both:

```
cmd := exec.Command("./slowroll")
combined, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
cmd.Stderr = cmd.Stdout // <-- use stdout pipe for stderr
if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

s := bufio.NewScanner(combined)
for s.Scan() {
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", s.Bytes())
}
```

The code in the question has a data race on the stdOut bytes.Buffer.

Answer (score 0):

`if err != timeout_io.ErrTimeout && err != io.EOF { ...; break; }`

With such a condition, an `ErrTimeout` will be silently ignored and will not interrupt your reading loop.

Also note that reaching `io.EOF` would send your program in an endless loop (try using `echo "Hello"` instead of `./slowroll` as a command).

---

You probably want to place the `break` instruction *after* the if block :

```
if err != timeout_io.ErrTimeout && err != io.EOF {
    fmt.Println("ReadLine got error", err)
}
break
```

Answer (score 0):

Realized late last night that I was kind of fighting go's standard behavior.

Should have explained that the goal was to be able to watch stdout and stderr at the same time.

Taking @Zombo's advice above, I switched to `cmd.StdoutPipe` and `cmd.StderrPipe`.

The main idea is to just have goroutines that read the pipes and put content found into channels, and then `select` between the channels.

So `slowroll.go` does not produce infinite output, to show that EOF doesn't cause a infinite loop:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    line := 1
    for {
        fmt.Println("This is line", line)
        line += 1
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        if line%3 == 0 {
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "This is error %d\n", line)
        }
        if line > 10 {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

And the simpler, working `watcher.go` is now:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    runCommand := &exec.Cmd{
        Path: "./slowroll",
    }
    stdOut, err := runCommand.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Can't create StdoutPipe:", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    stdErr, err := runCommand.StderrPipe()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Can't create StderrPipe:", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        defer wg.Done()

        err := runCommand.Run()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("failed due to error:", err)
            os.Exit(1)
        }
    }(&wg)

    wg.Add(1)

    stdOutChan := make(chan string, 1)
    go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        defer wg.Done()

        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdOut)
        for scanner.Scan() {
            stdOutChan <- string(scanner.Bytes())
        }
        fmt.Println("Ran out of stdout input, read thread bailing.")
        close(stdOutChan)
    }(&wg)

    wg.Add(1)

    stdErrChan := make(chan string, 1)
    go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        defer wg.Done()

        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdErr)
        for scanner.Scan() {
            stdErrChan <- string(scanner.Bytes())
        }
        fmt.Println("Ran out of stderr input, read thread bailing.")
        close(stdErrChan)
    }(&wg)

    wg.Add(1)

    index := 1
    keepGoing := true
    for keepGoing {
        select {
        case res, isOpen := <-stdOutChan:
            if !isOpen {
                fmt.Println("stdOutChan is no longer open, main bailing.")
                keepGoing = false
            } else {
                fmt.Println(index, "s:", res)
                index += 1
            }

        case res, isOpen := <-stdErrChan:
            if !isOpen {
                fmt.Println("stdErrChan is no longer open, main bailing.")
                keepGoing = false
            } else {
                fmt.Println(index, "error s:", res)
                index += 1
            }
        }
    }

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Done!")
}
```

Output:

```
    > go run watcher.go
    1 s: This is line 1
    2 s: This is line 2
    3 error s: This is error 3
    4 s: This is line 3
    5 s: This is line 4
    6 s: This is line 5
    7 s: This is line 6
    8 error s: This is error 6
    9 s: This is line 7
    10 s: This is line 8
    11 s: This is line 9
    12 error s: This is error 9
    13 s: This is line 10
    Ran out of stdout input, read thread bailing.
    stdOutChan is no longer open, main bailing.
    Ran out of stderr input, read thread bailing.
    Done!
```

Could stand with some refactoring, obviously, but it works, which is the goal.

Thanks!